# Error while using opencv_train cascade

Tags: opencv

I am trying to create my own haar cascade classifier for hand gesture recognition. After generating the sample images[positive and negative] and generating the .vec file, when i try to execute the opencv_trainascaded exe file, i get the following error :

"Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated."

Can anyone help me in this regard??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try opencv_haartraining function.

Comment: The command `opencv_haartraining` is deprecated. You should continue to use `opencv_traincascade`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try aligning the positive and negative samples to the same size - see the linked reference.

Code wise, it looks like the error is only thrown when attempting to get the negative and positive images, so you might also want to make sure you are telling the classifier exe the correct number of positive and negative training samples.

http://nmarkou.blogspot.com/2012/01/using-train-cascades.html

Answer (score 0):

check for the no of negative samples vs no. entries you have for them in .txt file.....