I can't use opencv_traincascade . Is always the same error
This is the command that I try to do:
C:\Users\gamer\PycharmProjects\bsbot\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\Users\gamer\PycharmProjects\bsbot\capturing\cascade -vec C:\Users\gamer\PycharmProjects\bsbot\pos.vec -bg C:\Users\gamer\PycharmProjects\bsbot\capturing\neg.txt -w 24 -h 24 -numPos 900 -numNeg 2500 -numStages 10
And this is the output I get:
===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   900 : 900
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.


I checked parameters
I try it in newer and older version of opencv
I deleted and created pos.vec again

There's just few information in the internet for my project, and I don't know what to do.

Some people saying there is a problem with 0-stage in some OpenCV version.

and there can be a problem about absolute path of neg.txt.



can you give more information about how much data you use? Is there something more displayed before you get this error message, or does this pop up immediately after the POS count was finished?

can you try with smaller numbers, like -numPos 300 -numNeg 500?

also check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412655/error-train-dataset-for-temp-stage-can-not-be-filled-while-using-traincascade
